# How to use :not and :first-child pseudo selectors simultaneously

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I want to select the first `li` **without** `class="test"` using `:not` and `:first-child` pseudoclasses. In this example I try to set color blue to `<li>Third</li>`:

```css
ul li {
    color:red;
}

ul li:not(.test):first-child {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="test">First</li>
    <li class="test">Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do the below, which uses a combination of rules to filter the item you need (you can combine rules #1 and #3).

This has the added advantage of it not mattering what the index is of the first item with the class `.test`

```css
ul li { /* <-- select all list items */
  color: red;
}
li:not(.test) { /* <-- select all list which arent test */
  color: blue;
}
ul li:not(.test) ~ li { /* <-- select all list items which follow an item without test */
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="test">First</li>
  <li class="test">Second</li>
  <li>Third</li>
  <li>Fourth</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Same principle: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107 If you need to avoid overriding certain values for `li.test` you can qualify `~ li` as `~ li:not(.test)` instead.